# how to get number from mysql django query result?

Tags: python, mysql, django

How to get just the number from this django mysql query?

```
Transaksi.objects.extra(select={'hasil':"Select sum(nominal) from transaksi_kas_transaksi as t Inner JOIN datapribadisiswa_datapribadisiswa as d on t.nis=d.SiswaNIS WHERE d.SiswaKelas_id=6"},where=["kode_pem='01' AND month(tanggal)=8 And (tanggal>=%s and tanggal<=%s)"],params=['2016-07-01','2017-06-30']).values_list('hasil', flat=True)
```

and this is the result

```
((Decimal('410000'),), (Decimal('410000'),), (Decimal('410000'),), (Decimal('410000'),), (Decimal('615000'),), (Decimal('410000'),), )
```

how to get number from the result?

Comment: Some reminders: 1. you usually don't do SQL in Django 2. You don't use string formating with `%` on SQL queries 3. There is `len()`.

Comment: A better way to fix this would be to use the ORM, instead of raw SQL.
One way you can get a list is to 1. Flatten the result set and then map the Decimal type to float type

Comment: please use django ORM for simple queries for sake of humanity!

Comment: Must Inner Join in django orm use foreign key? 
When i tried this query `Transaksi.objects.values('nominal','nis__SiswaNIS')`
I got this error `Cannot resolve keyword 'SiswaNIS' into field. Join on 'nis' not permitted`

Comment: I have change my code, and using extra from django orm

Comment: cant django orm do inner join without any relations?